# How much of the power used in a formula e race is from recovery vs initial battery capacity?

Tags: formula-e

In an average formula e race what sort of percentage energy usage comes from recovered powered vs the total energy used?

Is it a significant amount? Or is all the technology there for show? I.e a negligible amount of energy recovered etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching in many website for the answer of this question there is no data that shows percentage energy usage from recovered powered vs the total energy used.

In a website [fuel-efficient-vehicles.org](http://fuel-efficient-vehicles.org/energy-news/?p=1336) this one line states :

> Formula E car maximum power output will be 200kW equating to 270 horsepower and the vehicle will have a max regenerative capacity of 150kW, powered by the brakes as drivers enter corners and chicanes.

Formula E car has 320kg Rechargeable Energy Storage System (RESS) batteries which is connected with two MGU motors still lacks in power, so the car needs to be swapped mid way. [Working of power unit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1RlZF9j3NoE)

So technology is not all for the show and still regenerates some energy. This table shows energy recovered by MGU motors in formula one car, which is 160hp.
[image: Table Pic]

[Link to table website](http://jalopnik.com/how-formula-ones-amazing-new-hybrid-turbo-engine-works-1506450399)

In summary, from all data I have formula e have capacity to regenerate 150kw energy (Source given above), i'm not sure how much that comes out in percentage.